# The set of all real numbers $x$ such that $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value, radicals

The questions goes as

> The set of all real numbers $x$ such that $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ consists of
>
> a. Zero only
>   b. Nonpositive real numbers only
>   c. positive real numbers only
>   d. all real numbers
>   e. no real numbers

I chose b but I don't completely understand. I learned that the term "nonpositive real numbers" means that $0$ is included with all the numbers to negative infinity. I know that all positive real numbers have two square roots. Can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: $\sqrt{a}$ is the **non-negative** number whose square is $a$.

Comment: To expand on André Nicolas comment: While any positive real $a$ has two "square roots" (numbers $x$ such that $x^2 = a$), the symbol $\sqrt{a}$ specifically means the "principal square root", i.e., only the one positive root of for such numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You have $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.  Now the answer becomes clear.

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of the SAT, I encourage a number substitution approach, remembering to choose common exceptional cases.

Choose $x = 0$, a choice suggested by choice (A):  Then $\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{0^2} = 0$, and $-x = -0 = 0$, so the equation checks out.  This eliminates (C) and (E).

Next, choose $x = 1$:  we get $\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{1^2} = 1$, but $-x = -1$ which is false, thus eliminating (D).

Finally, choose $x = -1$:  we get $\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1$, and $-x = -(-1) = 1$, which works, eliminating choice (A).  Therefore, the answer must be choice (B).

It is a longer approach than knowing that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, but on the SAT, sometimes we don't always know the higher-level principle to be able to answer questions immediately, and instead the student can rely on lower-level principles as in this case, to guide oneself to a correct answer even if a proof is not known.

---

In regard to the way square roots are used on the SAT, it is made clear in the instructions for the mathematics sections that the notation $\sqrt{x}$ is intended to denote the unique nonnegative number whose square equals $x$; i.e., the *nonnegative* square root of $x$.  The SAT I does not require knowledge of complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $(b)$.

Since $\sqrt x^2=|x|$ and the definition of $|x|$ when $x<0$ is $-x$, which is usually how its defined in a Calculus I course.